# Como descobrir a operadora móvel do Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Estou a desenvolver um aplicativo no Eclipse e quero que ele funcione apenas em dispositivos de uma determinada operadora.

Alguma ideia como fazer para verificar a operadora?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você sabe sabia que você pode votar em qualquer coisa no site e pode aceitar uma resposta dada em perguntas feitas por você? Seria legal se puder revisar suas perguntas e ver se alguma resposta merece o voto e a aceitação.

Answer (score 14):

O Android disponibiliza a classe [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) que permite aceder a informação relacionada com o serviço telefónico.

Ela tem métodos que permitem aceder a alguns tipos de informação do assinante.
Entre eles está o [getNetworkOperatorName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName%28%29) que retorna a informação que você quer.

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String nomeOperadora = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```