# Problemas em conseguir IMEI e Nome da Operadora

Tags: java, android

eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e precisava manusear o TelephonyManager, porém, todo momento que vou utiliza-lo dá algum problema. Por exemplo:

> E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport

Já tentei pegar o Imei:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        String imei = telephonyManager.getImei();
```

Tentei pegar o nome da Operadora:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String nomeOperadora = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
            printarImei.setText(nomeOperadora);
```

Porém da sempre algum erro, as vezes erro de permissão mesmo concedendo a permissão no Manifest.xml...Agradeço desde já!! Obrigado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como descobrir a operadora móvel do Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48940/28595)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como recuperar o IMEI do celular programaticamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306453/28595)